# bash + read variables & values from file by bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, variable, eval

I have the following file variable and values

```
# more file.txt
export worker01="sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk"
export worker02="sdg sdh sdi sdj sdm"
export worker03="sdg sdh sdi sdj sdf"
```

I perform source in order to read the variable

```
# source file.txt
```

example:

```
echo $worker01
sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk
```

**until now every thing is perfect**

but now I want to read the variables from the file and print the values
by simple bash loop I will read the second field and try to print value of the variable

```
#  for i in ` sed s'/=/ /g'  /tmp/file.txt | awk '{print $2}' `
   do  
   echo $i
   declare var="$i"
   echo $var
   done
```

but its print only the variable and not the values

```
worker01
worker01
worker02
worker02
worker03
worker03
```

expected output:

```
worker01
sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk
worker02
sdg sdh sdi sdj sdm
worker03
sdg sdh sdi sdj sdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `export worker01="sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk"`, then you replace `=` with a space to get `export worker01 "sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk"`. The space separated fields in that are `export`, `worker01`, `"sdg`, `sdh`,  etc.

It's probably better to split on `=`, and remove the quotes, so with just the shell:

```
$ while IFS== read -r key val ; do
    val=${val%\"}; val=${val#\"}; key=${key#export };
    echo "$key = $val";
  done < vars
worker01 = sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk
worker02 = sdg sdh sdi sdj sdm
worker03 = sdg sdh sdi sdj sdf
```

`key` contains the variable name, `val` the value. Of course this doesn't actually parse the input, it just removes the double quotes if they happen to be there.

Answer (score 3):

With **awk** alone:

```
awk -F'"' '{print $2}' file.txt
# To print the variable name as well:
awk '{gsub(/[:=]/," "); gsub(/[:"]/,""); if ($1 = "export") {$1=""; print $0}}' file.txt
```

to loop it you can:

```
for i in "$(awk -F\" '{print $2}' file.txt)"; do
    var="$i"
    echo "$var"
done
my_array=($(awk -F\" '{print $2}' file.txt))
for element in "${my_var[@]}"; do
    another_var="$element"
    echo "$another_var"
done
```

If you also want to print the variable name in your loop you can do this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash -
while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$(awk '{print $1}' <<<"$line")" == 'export' ]]; then
        var_name="$(awk '{print $2}' <<<"$line" | awk -F'=' '{print $1}')"
        var_value="$(awk -F\" '{print $2}' <<<"$line")"
        echo -e "${var_name}\n${var_value}"
    else
        continue
    fi
done<file.txt
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh
worker01
sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk
worker02
sdg sdh sdi sdj sdm
worker03
sdg sdh sdi sdj sdf
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you can get the variables names with this GNU grep command, using a Perl-compat regex:

```
grep -oP 'export \K[^=]+' file.txt
```

Then, you can read the output of that into a bash array with:

```
mapfile -t variables < <(grep -oP 'export \K[^=]+' file.txt)
```

That uses the bash builtin [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) command and a [process substitition](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).

Last, iterate over the variable names and use [*indirect* parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to get the values:

```
for v in "${variables[@]}"; do 
    printf "varname=%s\tvalue=%s\n" "$v" "${!v}"
done
```

```
varname=worker01        value=sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk
varname=worker02        value=sdg sdh sdi sdj sdm
varname=worker03        value=sdg sdh sdi sdj sdf
```

Comment: Working through this answer and learning all the techniques used here taught me a lot about bash, parameters and modifying shell behavior. I highly recommend iterating and researching until one understands everything mentioned in it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed

```
sed -E 's/[^ ]* ([^=]*)="([^"]*)"/\1\n\2/' file.txt
```

Or this awk

```
awk -F '"|=' '{split($1,a," ");print a[2]"\n"$3}' file.txt
```